# How can I open URLs from a CSV file with selenium?

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-scholar

I'm trying to save the data from a profile on Google Scholar into a CSV. The profile has a ‘Show More’ button, and I can get all the data from it (here I only saved the data from the table but I need all the data from the profile) but the problem is that I saved the data twice or even more times sometimes, and I think it's because I saved it while I was clicking and not after I had clicked all the ‘Show More’, so how can I do that? Also, here I used only one URL, but there are more, and I have them saved in another CSV, so how do I open each URL from there to do what I do here? (I only need the Link row) the CSV with the URLs look like this
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zkTlzYaOQ7FVoSdd5OMnE8QgwS8NOik7/view?usp=sharing

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as W
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions as SE
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from csv import writer

chrome_path=r"C:\Users\gvste\Desktop\proyecto\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

urls = ["https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=gQb_tFMAAAAJ"]

button_locators = "//button[@class='gs_btnPD gs_in_ib gs_btn_flat gs_btn_lrge gs_btn_lsu']"
wait_time = 2

wait = W(driver, wait_time)

for url in urls:
    data = {}
    driver.get(url)

    button_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_locators)))

    while button_link:
        try:
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'gsc_a_tw')))
            data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gsc_a_tr")



            button_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_locators)))
            button_link.click()
            time.sleep(2)

            with open('perfil.csv','a', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as s:
                 csv_writer =writer(s)
                 for i in range(len(data)):
                     paper = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gsc_a_t")
                     citas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gsc_a_c")
                     año = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gsc_a_y")  
                     p = paper[i].text.replace(',', '')
                     c = citas[i].text.replace(',', '')
                     a = año[i].text.replace(',', '')            
                     csv_writer.writerow([ p, c, a])

        except SE.TimeoutException:
            print(f'Página parseada {url}')
            break

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part I didn't really get what's happening. But for the second part you can change URLs from hard code to a function (put the loop in function) and you can use pandas library for CSV (it's much better). This is for getting the URLS

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
urls = df['column_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most basic way read data from CSV file:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader(filename)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```